# Sql server Execution Plans not considering the non clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Below is query we have non clustered index on  Questionnaire_Number column but optimizer choosing index scan and it its taking almost 39% of query operations.

```
 SELECT
  [Country],
  [Site],
  [Subject],
  [Questionnaire],
  [Ques],
  [Res],
  [ReceivedDt],
  [CompletedDt],
  [CompletedDtlc],
  [Questionnaire],
  [RecordUpdaChange],
  [ChangeRequesiser],
  [RecordUpdated],
  [CompletedQuestionnaireId],
  [EnrollmentDt],
  [AppVersion],
  [CompletedBY],
  [ModeofEntry],
  [StudyDay]
FROM [dbo].Report_PerformTest A
JOIN #Questionnaire_Number Q
  ON A.Questionnaire_Number = Q.Questionnaire_Number
ORDER BY CountryName, Site, Subject, CompletedDateTimeLc
```

[Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRKEd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvuPM.png)

Index Details :

```
CLUSTERED INDEX : CompletedQuestionnaireId;    
    
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NIX_Dairy_data_Summary
ON [Report_performTest] SiteID,SubjectNo
INCLUDE   All selected columns   
    
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NIXQues_Dairy_data_Summary
ON [Report_performTest](Questionnaire_Number)
INCLUDE  All selected columns
```

Could please let me know how to avoid index scan on this

Comment: The optimizer is choosing the execution plan that it determines is the best for this query.  Do you have a question?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  in second image it is warning  like this operation caused residual.is it hit the performance degrade . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes are not used because the ORDER BY clause specify some columns that are not a part of the "KEY" clause or the INCLUDE clause of your index, like CountryName.